# Setting font in html for UILabel attributed text is not working

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

Html text with `font-size` or setting `UIFont` on `UILabel` is making the `NSAttributedText` to not render properly.

```
extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedLabelString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = NSString(string: self).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) else { return nil }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                          options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                          documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {}
        return nil
    }
}
```

```
let lbl = UILabel()
lbl.attributedText = "<span style=\"font-size: 22px\"; Please read the <b>Nomination Guidelines</b> before completing this form.".htmlToAttributedLabelString
```

This is not rendering bold. Same issue if I try to set the font manually to the label. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `html text` that you are using, the `span` tag is not closed.

Try changing the value of `lbl.attributedText` to:

```
lbl.attributedText = "<span style=\"font-size: 22px\">; Please read the <b>Nomination Guidelines</b> before completing this form.".htmlToAttributedLabelString
```

**Output:**

[image]